# How to find last node that satisfies where predicate in singly linked list?

Tags: kotlin, linked-list, higher-order-functions

1. **write a method "lastWhere" that accepts a function called "where" of type (T) -> Boolean. The method returns the last element of type T to which the "where" function applies. If no matching element is found, null is returned.**
2. **call the method "lastwhere" on the linked list below. Find the last game that is more than 10 euros.**

So far I've got this Code going for me.

I assume the only important piece of Code I need to edit is the "fun lastWhere" for task number 1)

the second task wants me to implement a way on the main function to find the last Game that is cheaper than 10 Euros.

```
class LinkedList<T> {
    data class Node<T>(val data: T, var next: Node<T>?)

    private var first: Node<T>? = null

    override fun toString(): String = first?.toString() ?: "-"

    fun isEmpty() = first == null

    fun addLast(data: T) {
        if (first == null) {
            first = Node(data, first)
            return
        }

        var runPointer = first
        while (runPointer?.next != null) {
            runPointer = runPointer.next
        }
        runPointer?.next = Node(data, null)
    }

    fun lastWhere (where: (T) -> Boolean): T? {   // "where" function needs to be implemented
        if (isEmpty()) return null
        else {
            var runPointer = first
            while (runPointer?.next != null ) {
                runPointer = runPointer.next
            }
            return runPointer?.data
        }
    }

}

data class Game(val title: String, val price: Double)

fun main() {
    val list = LinkedList<Game>()
    list.addLast(Game("Minecraft", 9.99))
    list.addLast(Game("Overwatch", 29.99))
    list.addLast(Game("Mario Kart", 59.99))
    list.addLast(Game("World of Warcraft", 19.99))

    var test = list.lastWhere ({it.price >= 10.00})  // This is probably wrong too, since I haven't got task 1) working
    println (test)
}
```

Would appreciate any help!

Comment: I assume this is some homework assignment - you have to run the higher order function that is passed into `lastWhere` and keep track of the last element for which the passed in function returns `true` (eg. `lastValid: T?`). When you run out of elements to evaluate simply return `lastValid`.

Comment: Off topic question, but why are like 90% of homework problems on here about creating your own LinkedList implementation?

Comment: Well I can only speak for me - LinkedList is a new subject for me right now, hence the question.

I thought about using a counter for the task, but I don't think it's the right solution..

Comment: @Tenfour04 at a guess they still teach basic data structures, and get you to roll your own to demonstrate the concept, instead of going "just use whatever the language conveniently provides for you". Probably the same reason everyone's wild about ``ArrayList``s! Maybe some big online course is covering it right now

Answer (score 0):

Since you only store a reference to first node, you don't have any choice but to start at first and iterate. you will also have to keep a reference to last item that satisfied the where predicate, and keep updating this reference with every iteration.

```
fun lastWhere (where: (T) -> Boolean): T? { 
    var runPointer = first
    var item: T? = null    // init item to null, if nothing is found we return null
    while (runPointer != null ) {
        // For every node, execute the where function and if it returns true
        // then update the return value 
        if(where(runPointer.data)) { item = runPointer.data }
        runPointer = runPointer.next
    }
    return item
}
```